# Rails how to only call custom validate method if attribute is present on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to only call a custom validate method when it is a new record or the attribute is present on update.

```
validates :mobile_number, presence: {
  message: 'Please provide your phone number.'
}, if: -> (user) { user.new_record? || !user.mobile_number.blank? }
```

The above code works and will only validate the presence of a mobile number on a new_record or if the mobile number is blank when model.update(etc.) is called.

```
validate :mobile_number_is_unique, if: -> (user) { user.new_record? || !user.mobile_number.blank? }
```

The above code does not work and will validate the uniqueness of a mobile number on a new_record and whenever model.update(etc.) is called.
Is there a way to apply the same logic to the validate method so that it does not get called when the mobile number is blank when model.update(etc.) is called?

`mobile_number_is_unique` method for further context,

```
# Determines if the mobile number is unique.
def mobile_number_is_unique
  return errors.add(
    :mobile_number, 'Sorry, an account with that phone number already exists.'
  ) unless User.find_by(
    mobile_number: PhonyRails.normalize_number(mobile_number)
  ).nil?
end
```

UPDATE

Cleanest way to accomplish:

```
validates :mobile_number, presence: {
  message: 'Please provide your phone number.'
}, phony_plausible: {
  message: 'Sorry, phone number format not recognized.'
}, uniqueness: {
  message: 'Sorry, an account with that phone number already exists.'
}, if: -> (user) { user.new_record? || !user.mobile_number.blank? }
```

Using the validate :mobile_number_is_unique method included the mobile number on the current model and needed to exclude it in order to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking if a mobile number already exists **including** the one that belongs to the user that you are currently editing. You should be able to just use:

`validates :mobile_number, uniqueness: true`

If you would prefer the custom validation method, you can use the following to exclude the selected user:

```
validate :mobile_number_is_unique

# Determines if the mobile number is unique.
def mobile_number_is_unique
  if new_record? || !mobile_number.blank?
    return errors.add(
      :mobile_number, 'Sorry, an account with that phone number already exists.'
    ) unless User.where(mobile_number: PhonyRails.normalize_number(mobile_number)).where.not(id: id).count == 0
  end
end
```

> OLD Version

Yes, you can just move the if statement into the `mobile_number_is_unique` method.

So it would become this:

```
validate :mobile_number_is_unique

# Determines if the mobile number is unique.
def mobile_number_is_unique
  if new_record? || !mobile_number.blank?
    return errors.add(
      :mobile_number, 'Sorry, an account with that phone number already exists.'
    ) unless User.find_by(
      mobile_number: PhonyRails.normalize_number(mobile_number)
    ).nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: same as @vishal's suggestion. Moving to have an if statement inside the method also does not work. After updating and setting u = User.first in the rails console, and then checking u.valid? I get false. The error message: {:mobile_number=>["Sorry, an account with that phone number already exists."]}

Comment: @Reason That is because you're checking if a mobile number already exists **including** the one that you're currently editing. Can you just use `validates :mobile_number, uniqueness: true`? If not, let me know and I'll modify my answer again.

Comment: Yep I believe that is correct and an interesting difference between validates and validate

Comment: Nice, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 4):

You only need to check validation if mobile number is present in record. so you can use below code .

```
validate :mobile_number_is_unique


# Determines if the mobile number is unique.
def mobile_number_is_unique
  return unless mobile_number.present?
  errors.add(
    :mobile_number, 'Sorry, an account with that phone number already exists.'
  ) unless User.find_by(
    mobile_number: PhonyRails.normalize_number(mobile_number)
  ).nil?
end
```

Comment: Moving to have a guard clause inside the method also does not work. After updating and setting u = User.first in the rails console, and then checking u.valid? I get false. The error message: {:mobile_number=>["Sorry, an account with that phone number already exists."]}

Comment: Logically if it's not present why we are doing validation on it? Yes as per my opinion OP was checking  wrong condition in proc

Comment: @Reason are you reloading console after changing code in model ?

Comment: The logic should be that if it IS present on update the validation is run against it.

Comment: I'm restarting the console after changing the code to the model, so yes.

Comment: Can you please add in question what you are doing with all field values ?

Comment: @Reason There is something you misunderstood, because there is no rocket science behind it, it should definitely work for condition in proc/method.

Comment: It's a private project, so no, but I can assure you that the method listed above is the only one that would produce such an error message and all other validations are of the type using the "validates" and work correctly against rspec testing.

Comment: I agree, I'm very confused on as to why it isn't working

Comment: @Reason yes exactly its not that complicated it is simple validation. i am pretty confident my code will work as expected.

Comment: @Reason there is nothing to do with private as it will throw error or get called! so condition works proper then it is finite!

Comment: In the console after setting u = User.first and doing u.mobile_number.present? it returns true, so I imagine that would lead to the issue. I'm not sure how the validations with "validates" are only seeing "updated" attributes, but that seems far stranger to me.